# Access only first value of variable

Tags: r

I have this function which gives this variable that supposedly returns the pivot row for a gaussian elimination code

```
a <- matrix(c(0.1, 3.0, 0.3, 7.0, -0.1, -0.2, -0.3, -0.2, 10.0, -19.3, 7.85, 71.40), 
            nrow=3, ncol=4)
n <- nrow(a)
for (i in 2:n - 1) {
  prow <- which(a == max(abs(a[i:n, i])))
  print(prow)
}
```

However, whenever I get the value from prow, it returns two values formed like a column, but isnt.

Example of matrix input:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]   [,4]
[1,]  0.1  7.0 -0.3 -19.30
[2,]  3.0 -0.1 -0.2   7.85
[3,]  0.3 -0.2 10.0  71.40
```

Result I get from the function

```
[1] 2
integer(0)
```

Is it possible to just get the first value among the two so I can access the row in question

Comment: Yes, what have you tried?

Comment: @user2974951 Hi i tried indexing it as I thought it was a vector or list of some sort but to no avail. Its typeof() also returns two values so Im a bit lost

Answer (score 0):

```
which(a==(max(abs(a[1:n,1]))))
```

As you have a 3X3 matrix, the loop will run twice, printing two numbers. The first loop is the code line above and returns 2. The second loop returns integer(0)